# How to separate admin and users on query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cookies

I am trying to let users to create a book detail in a table called books. However there are two types of users which are admin and users. Admin are saved as type = 1 and users are saved as type = 0 in a user table in the database as boolean.

The user has to log into the system to update the book account. The detail of the user is saved as username in COOKIES.

Therefore I want to command computer that let only admin to upload book table relating to the COOKIES username and check the username is related to admin, if username is user don't let it create.

*Users*

```
id | name | type
 1 | abc  | 1  
 2 | xyz  | 0
```

I am trying to do such as

```
$_COOKIE['username']; 


$result = 'SELECT type FROM users WHERE type = 1'; 
$res = mysql_query($result); 

if ($res){

//let admin to enter the details 

} else {
//you are not an admin, 

}
```

Comment: That's nice looking forward to see when you have some code.

Comment: @Prix, please have a look, I have updated the question and input the code

Comment: seems like u already have the answer in your question...

Comment: You're part way there! Just gotta fill in those sections where you have the comments.

Comment: there is no correlation between the mysql code and your goal the // stuff is where the meat of your issue is and your not displaying anything. please submit the complete algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query will always return 1. You want something along the lines of

```
$username = $_COOKIE['username'];
$res = mysql_query("SELECT type FROM users WHERE name='$username'");
```

Then check if the type is 1 or 0.

```
$row = $mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
if ($row['type'] == 1){
    //You are an admin
} else {
    //You are not an admin
}
```

It doesn't matter if you use cookies or sessions. You need to pass some sort of user information, whether it's the user's id or username, into your SQL query to check that specific user's credentials.

Comment: Of course, this system is incredibly insecure because there's nothing stopping me from changing my cookie so the username is an admin's username.

Comment: But how can I clarify the type ? Right now, I will be only getting username but not type of that username. Isn't?

Comment: Also, you really should be using PDO or mysqli functions instead.

Comment: You get the *username* from the cookie. Then you use the username to query the *database* to get the type for that username.

Comment: So I have done something like $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
$res = mysql_query("SELECT type FROM users WHERE name='$username' AND type = 1");, But it won't work

Comment: Why are you putting the "AND type=1" in there? Look at the SQL I wrote. Use that. Then check the value of "type" that it returns.

Comment: Now it says mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result on the line $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

Comment: That should have been mysql_fetch_assoc not mysqli, but it would be a good idea to go ahead and learn/implement mysqli at this stage in development.

Answer (score 0):

Now, suppose you have a php file called **upload.php** which handles the book upload. Now, in the file check if the session variable `$_SESSION["type"]` has a value of 1 i.e, the logged -in-user is an admin. Also, I would advise against using mysql_* syntax anymore since its deprecated. Take a look at [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). I have written my answer using mysqli.

```
//This code goes in upload.php file

$mysqli = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DBNAME);

$username = $_COOKIE["username"];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT type FROM users WHERE username=?");
if($stmt){
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute;
    $stmt->bind_result($type);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}

//Now check for type
if( $type == 1){
     //Add upload code here
}
else{
     //Not admin access denied
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: I have updated the question., I am using cookies to save it. Please have a look it.

Comment: I have used cookies to save username but how can i save the type ?